# My fish pond I was wondering if the water will evaporate quicker with the water fall running and blowing air into the pond with an air stone

Tags: water, evaporation

Hi I keep thinking that my pond has a leak I have just emptied and cleaned the pond and made sure there was no leaks as I could see. When running the pond water is being pumped through sealed pressurized filters then down a 3 tier water fall also have 2 air stones blowing air in to help with oxygen levels, I was wondering if the evaporation would be greater with the air bubbles blowing through than with out the air bubbles and also would anyone know approximately how much water will evaporate in Spring and Summer the pond is sort of kidney shaped 13 foot long and 9 foot wide at the widest point thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Air bubbles increase the area of interface between water and vapour phases, which increases the rate of evaporation. Evaporation will continue until the vapour in contact with the water reaches saturation, which depends on temperature. Higher temperature means higher saturation level.

Same with the waterfall - it increases the area of interface.

Forced convection due to breezes across the pond will also have a significant effect. This reduces the concentration of vapour in contact with the water, which prevents the rate of evaporation from slowing as vapour concentration increases.

A typical evaporation rate is 5mm per day. Calculations - even estimates - can be quite unreliable. Better make your own measurement - eg how much water do you need to add to restore the water level to its original position?

[https://www.nationalpolyindustries.com.au/2018/06/14/how-much-water-do-swimming-pools-lose-each-day/#:~:text=The%20rate%20of%20water%20evaporation,is%20with%20a%20bucket%20test](https://www.nationalpolyindustries.com.au/2018/06/14/how-much-water-do-swimming-pools-lose-each-day/#:%7E:text=The%20rate%20of%20water%20evaporation,is%20with%20a%20bucket%20test).

Comment: But how much does the splashing & airstones in the waterfall affect the net total evap?  My guess is less than a few percent.  So your point about making actual measurements is spot-on